# Locking in navigation labels before changing title?

Tags: menus, navigation, labels

How can I stop menu navigation labels from changing when the page titles change.

I often use a bulk page adder to create the hierarchy I need. However, once I change a page title, the navigation label gets updated as well.

Is there any way with code to lock navigation labels titles and separate them from the active page titles?

Answer (score 1):

You can always edit navigation labels for each page in the *Menu Structure* section of the *Menus* admin page. Once the label becomes edited it will remain the same after the page title change.

[image]